# Is there a normal function where infinite cardinals are exactly the fixed points?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

A normal function is an increasing function $F\colon \mathrm{Ord} \to \mathrm{Ord}$ where for limit $\alpha$, $F(\alpha) = \sup_{\beta < \alpha} F(\beta)$. Every normal function has arbitrarily large fixed points, and enumerating them makes a new normal function. Examples of normal functions are $\alpha \mapsto \omega^\alpha, \alpha \mapsto \epsilon_\alpha, \alpha \mapsto \omega_\alpha$. The first two maps preserves cardinality for infinite ordinals, easily proved with $\mathsf{AC}$ because successor step preserves cardinality, and without $\mathsf{AC}$ because they are absolute between $L$ and $V$. It follows that they fix uncountable cardinals. But there are non-cardinal fixed points, for example $\epsilon_0$ for the first. Is there a normal function where the set of infinite cardinals, or some tail segment of it is exactly the fixed points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Suppose that $\omega_1$ is a fixed point of some function $F(\alpha)$, then $F(\omega_1)=\omega_1$. Since the function is normal, that means that $\alpha<\omega_1$ implies that $F(\alpha)<\omega_1$ as well.

But now we can show that there is a club of fixed points below $\omega_1$. The same holds for any uncountable cofinality.

One way around this would be to consider a model of $\sf ZF$ in which every infinite ordinal has countable cofinality, but off the cuff that's not going to work either since it will require you to identify a countable cofinal sequence in each ordinal, which seems like a bit more choice than what you'd usually have.<sup>1</sup>

---

1. That's not to say that it's inconsistent or impossible. It may very well be doable. You'd still need to come up with that definition, though. Probably if $\alpha_n$ is the cofinal sequence up to $\omega_\alpha$, you'd like to have something like $F(\xi)$ to be the least $\alpha_n$ above $\xi$ (in the appropriate interval), and the identity on the cardinals.

   But frankly, that seems like we're trying too hard.

Comment: Can we also consider the case where there can be cardinals with uncountable confinality and the clubs turn out to be only cardinals? Well with $\mathsf{AC}$ this will be impossible because successor cardinals are regular.

Comment: Successor cardinals are successors. So there is no club of cardinals below a successor, regardless of AC.

Comment: Yes. What I meant was if there exist arbitrarily large successor cardinals with uncountable cofinality, no normal function has the set of infinite cardinals, or some tail segment of it as exactly the fixed points. With $\mathsf{AC}$ this is true. So I was wondering if it's possible to circumvent this (without $\mathsf{AC}$ of course) but still allow cardinals with uncountable cofinality.

Comment: @Ris if a successor aleph number, κ+, has uncountable cofinality, and κ+ is a fixed point, then there exists a non-cardinal fixed point between κ and κ+ by simply looking at the sequence {κ+1, f(κ+1),f^2(κ+1),...}(where +1 is a ordinal addition). This does not use AC.

Comment: @ℋolo Yes that is right. I was asking about if we can have a model without "arbitrarily large successor cardinals with uncountable cofinality" not a model with "successor cardinals with uncountable cofinality where there is a club of cardinals". If you misunderstood sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @Ris: As I said, there are models in which all infinite ordinals have a countable cofinality.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. I understood that, but this was dropped in my latest comment: My question in the comments above was whether we can have a model with that property where there still exist cardinals with uncountable cofinality, circumventing your refutation.

Comment: @Ris: So you want to have a model where every successor cardinal has countable cofinality, but some limit cardinals don't? These kind of results are pretty hardcore. I am sure it's consistent, relative to the right large cardinal axioms, but these are not easy results that one can just confidently pull out of their pocket. Let me add that in the countable cofinality case you're going to weaken "increasing" to "non-decreasing" anyway, or else you'd be pressed to find a neater trick to still have "increasing" betwixt the points in the cofinal sequence.